# VSFTPD not letting me login

Tags: 14.04, firewall, vsftpd

Any one come across this before, Other then the settings below everything is default. This seems to work on my local machine but not on a VPS

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
```

I've opened the ports.

It connects to the server but rejects the user, I know I have the correct password, its *qwerty* ffs and the user is my name so i'm not getting the credentials wrong.

```
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Command:    USER dale
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:          Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: can you try using the command line to login? (as opposed to a browser) does the user have permission to access their home folder?

Comment: I can ssh into the user, when I do i get this message: Could not chdir to home directory /home/dale: No such file or directory Is that the problem the user isn't setup correctly?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by opening */etc/shells* and adding the following line at the end

```
/usr/sbin/nologin
```